# How to use the `provider` and retrieve the data in `controller`

Tags: angularjs, angular-providers

I am trying to use a `provider` to set and get a value in the controller. But I am not clear on how to use the `provider` here.

Can any one help me to use the `provider` with `config` option. I would like to know about the relationship between `provider` and `config` as well.

Here is my try, which throws error:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.value("person", {'name':"arif"});

app.constant("env", {url:"production"});

app.provider("book", function(){ //declaring provider
  var version;
  return {
    setVersion : function(value){
      version = value;
    },

    $get : function(school){
      return {
        "newVersion" : "title" + ':' + version
      }
    }
  }
});

app.config(function(newBook){ //setting a new value
    newBook.setVersion = "4.0";
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, person, env, book) {
  $scope.name = env.url;
  $scope.value = person.name;
  $scope.version = book; //i am not getting the new value here.
});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8drfme2ShqxdBJFodhNl?p=preview)

Comment: Shouldn't you inject `bookProvider` and call `bookProvider.setVersion('4.0')` in your `config`?

Comment: The errors in your console should have provided you some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment...

```
app.config(function(bookProvider){
    bookProvider.setVersion("4.0");
});
```

I had to remove the missing `school` injection to get it to work but you should get the picture.

Fixed ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/6Sb6rOSvA7ihvTLPTujY?p=preview

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe for more information on the *provider* recipe.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider for the `.provider()` docs, specifically...

> NOTE: the provider will be available under `name + 'Provider'` key.

Comment: I agree. I have a doubt here, how `app.config(function(bookProvider)` connect to provider book? `(app.provider("book",function())`? can you help me to understand?

Comment: refering to you plunker ,there is no function name given in `$.get : ` and we call book in controller??

Comment: @pro.mean nor should there be. The name is the first arg passed to `app.provider()`. The `$get` function is defined in the object returned by the provider constructor function as part of the [spec](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider). I suggest you read the documentation links above carefully

Comment: I change return on setVerion and tried with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R2YBaoANQiJGzkLnNflT?p=preview) but it does not work? what can be the issue

Comment: @pro.mean you should open a new question. In any case, `setVersion` is not part of the object returned by the provider

Comment: @Phil : see my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850557/with-no-named-function-for-get-in-provider-is-working-fine